# media9 seems to conflict with xr-hyper

Tags: hyperref, media9, zref

A year ago everything was fine with my book. But now compilation fails. I managed to localize my problem to the  following MWE. The following error occurs when pdflatex runs over second file (`B.tex`):

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\XR@explist ->\expandafter \XR@next \XR@list 
                                             \\
l.14 \zexternaldocument
                       [A-]{A}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Argument of \XR@next has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.14 \zexternaldocument
                       [A-]{A}
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.

Runaway argument?
\\
! Paragraph ended before \XR@next was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.14 \zexternaldocument
                       [A-]{A}
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.

! Too many }'s.
<recently read> }

l.14 \zexternaldocument
                       [A-]{A}
You've closed more groups than you opened.
Such booboos are generally harmless, so keep going.
```

Here is my first file `A.tex`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{media9}

% Package xr-hyper needs to be loaded before hyperref 
% but \externaldocument should be given after loading hyperref:

\usepackage{xr-hyper} 
\usepackage[user,xr]{zref} 
\usepackage{zref-xr} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\externaldocument[B-]{B} 
\zexternaldocument[B-]{B}


\begin{document}

empty page

\newpage \section{Dittmer}\label{Dittmer}\zlabel{Dittmer}

Dittmer

\newpage \section{Langmuir}\label{Langmuir}\zlabel{Langmuir}

Langmuir

\newpage \section{References}

\hyperref[Dittmer]{hyperref to Dittmer} on page \pageref{Dittmer}, \zpageref{Dittmer}

\hyperref[Langmuir]{hyperref to Langmuir} on page \pageref{Langmuir}, \zpageref{Langmuir}

\hyperref[B-Shafranov]{hyperref to B-Shafranov} on page \pageref{B-Shafranov}, \zpageref{B-Shafranov}

\hyperref[B-Stupakov]{hyperref to B-Stupakov} on page \pageref{B-Stupakov}, \zpageref{B-Stupakov}

\begin{figure}[!tp]\centering
        \includemedia[
            width=\linewidth,height=0.528\linewidth,
            activate=pageopen,%onclick
            addresource=Video/2012-05-09.mp4,
            flashvars={%
                src={Video/2012-05-09.mp4}%
                &muted=true%
                &loop=true%
                &controlBarAutoHideTimeout=2%
            }
        ]{}{StrobeMediaPlayback.swf}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:05-09} \end{figure} \end{document}
```

And here is my second source file `B.tex`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[user,xr]{zref}
\usepackage{zref-xr}
\externaldocument[A-]{A}
\zexternaldocument[A-]{A}

\begin{document}

empty page

\newpage
\section{Shafranov}\label{Shafranov}\zlabel{Shafranov}

Shafranov

\newpage
\section{Stupakov}\label{Stupakov}\zlabel{Stupakov}

Stupakov

\newpage
\section{References}

\hyperref[A-Dittmer]{hyperref to A-Dittmer} on page \pageref{A-Dittmer}, \zpageref{A-Dittmer}

\hyperref[A-Langmuir]{hyperref to A-Langmuir} on page \pageref{A-Langmuir}, \zpageref{A-Langmuir}

\hyperref[Shafranov]{hyperref to Shafranov} on page \pageref{Shafranov}, \zpageref{Shafranov}

\hyperref[Stupakov]{hyperref to Stupakov} on page \pageref{Stupakov}, \zpageref{Stupakov}

\end{document}
```

The above indicated error disappears if I remove `\includemedia` macro which imports video. So, a bug is suspected in `mmedia`, which is most often renovated package among all other packages loaded in this MWE.

Comment: Both files compile here. Of course, some warnings are produced, due to missing `A-Dittmer`, `A-Langmuir`, `B-Shafranov`,  `B-Stupakov`, `A.aux` and `B.aux` files.

Comment: @AlexG: I am sorry, please rename C.tex to A.tex and D.tex to B.tex. Note that I checked the problem under latest versions of both MikTeX and TeX Live.

Comment: Ok, thanks. This is a bug which will be fixed in the next version that I am going to upload now.

Comment: Please, remove the braces around the file name in the `flashvars` option: `src={Video/2012-05-09.mp4}` --> `src=Video/2012-05-09.mp4`. For `addresource`, the braces are ok if you want to hide commas in the file name, e.g. `addresource={<file name, with comma>}`.

Comment: @AlexG: Thank you, with yesterday's version of `media9` now it works!

Comment: Then I think, we may close this question. Thanks once again for reporting.

Comment: The question can be closed because it is about a bug that has been fixed meanwhile. A new version of the affected package is available online (CTAN).

Comment: @AlexG: I also think that the question can be closed.